# What object types are inserted by pymongo into mongodb as BinData?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I have been working with `pymongo 3.3.0` and `mongo 3.2.10` on a `Ubuntu 14.04` machine for a while. Recently, I noticed that some of my records are inserted with BinData type instead of string, which is what I expect.

I now have records that look like this:

```
{'some_key': BinData(0,"S0me=Bas3=64=Enc0Ding")}
```

Although I would have expected something like this:

```
{'some_key': 'some_value'}
```

I noticed that if I decode `S0me=Bas3=64=Enc0Ding`, I get the expected value, `some_value`.

However, I am still confused as to why this is happening.

I checked my code and it appears that I am inserting strings. Additionally, the bug is not general. I still have new records inserted correctly. Only some of them are inserted as BinData.

> Do you know any gotchas that might lead to this problem, or have any
>   suggestions on what to check as a potential source of the issue?

Realising the quetion might be too broad, I will narrow it down like this:

> What object types are inserted by pymongo into mongodb as BinData?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The python version I am using is 3.5. While the specific version does not matter, the fact that I am using python 3 does.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the bug.

One of my methods was returning a byte string instead of a string.

For example, if you have this:

```
value = b'some_value'
collection.insert_one({'some_key': value})
```

You will end up in Mongo with:

```
{'some_key': BinData(0,"S0me=Bas3=64=Enc0Ding")}
```

I suspect this has something to do with the fact `string` and `bytes` are no longer subclasses of `basestring`.